# Have a issue with request routed53omains API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

There was a problem accessing the routedomains module API.

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
#encoding: utf-8
import boto3

key_id='xxxxxxxx'
access_key='xxxxxxxx'
client = boto3.client(
        'route53domains',
        aws_access_key_id = key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key = access_key,
        region_name = 'us-east-1'
)
all_domains= client.list_domains(DomainName="mydomain.com")
print(all_domains)
```

Run result:

```
[]
```

I can confirm that there are more than one domainame under the account(key_id and access_key).
and given sufficient permissions：

- AmazonRoute53DomainsFullAccess
- AmazonRoute53FullAccess

But response is null.

And request Route53 modules api is not problem:

```
client = boto3.client(
        'route53',
        region_name = 'us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        aws_secret_access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
)
client.get_paginator('list_hosted_zones')
```

My other account both Route53 and Route53domain  request is work ok !

why? What's the problem? please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The actual syntax for Route53domains client operation to list all the domains is:

```
response = client.list_domains(
    Marker='string',
    MaxItems=123
)
```

If the number of domains that are associated with the current AWS account is greater than the value that you specified for MaxItems , you can use Marker to return additional domains.

Refer to the boto3 [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53domains.html#Route53Domains.Client.list_domains) for Route53Domains

Comment: sory ,  I write code wrong,but client.list_domains(
    Marker='string',
    MaxItems=123) is not ok

Answer (score 0):

thank for your answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
#encoding: utf-8
import boto3

key_id='xxxxxxxx'
access_key='xxxxxxxx'
client = boto3.client(
        'route53domains',
        aws_access_key_id = key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key = access_key,
        region_name = 'us-east-1'
)
all_domains= client.list_domains(MaxItems=123)
print(all_domains)
```

run result:

```
{'Domains': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '2aa6e538-66e3-11e8-a89f-273ad6c882c8', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '2aa6e538-66e3-11e8-a89f-273ad6c882c8', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '14', 'date': 'Sun, 03 Jun 2018 04:04:09 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Domains is []

Sorry, I originally wanted to ask get_domain_detail() function:

```
Client.get_domain_detail(DomainName="mytest.com")
```

but found use that list_domains doesn't even have a domainname,

so,written error。

And I use the CMD API tool is still the same result:

```
./aws route53domains list-domains  --max-items 123
{
    "Domains": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be an aws account or background issue. I don't know why.